# Change of "home" results in timeouts (only on index.php)

Tags: wp-config, site-url, home-url

So this question is probably a result of me not completely understanding the inner workings of Wordpress - especially the *home* variable.

So here is what I did, and after that I will ask my question.

I did set up a Wordpress on localhost (with a remote database). Then I set up a fileserver for everything (except my .php files) and added it via the *cdn-enabler*.
Now I uploaded my Webiste to AWS and exposed it to the world via an *API-gateway*, while still using the old database. The website does work well now, even if I shut down my localhost server.

Since my hyperlinks still point to localhost (eg. /about_me would point to localhost/wordpress/about_me), I changed the *home* in *wp-config* to "myurl/stage".
Now if an go to "myurl/stage/about_me" I will see the about_me page just fine, but as soon as I go to "myurl/stage/index.php" I will get a timeout.

The error persists, either if I only set *home*, or if I set *home* and *siteurl*.
If I only change the *siteurl* the *cdn-enabler* will stop working, but I can access "myurl/stage/index.php", also all my hyperlinks will point to index.php, e.g: "myurl/stage/index.php/about_me".

Does anyone have a idea what happened here?
Can you give me a better insight in how exactly *home* and *siteurl* behave?

ps.: Maybe its important to note, that if I set *home* to "myurl" instead of "myurl/stage" I can access "myurl/stage/index.php". Sadly, if I do this all hyperlinks are broken again. Example: "myurl/about_me"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. This behaviour was due to a redirect loop from "home" to "home".

Adding the following line to wp-setting.php dit it for me. Sadly this is only a workaround. Maybe someone can hint me to a better fix.
    remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');